# How to change the default crawlStorageFolder in Crawler4j?

Tags: java, parsing, web-crawler, jsoup, crawler4j

When i try the Quickstart of Crawler4j [example](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j) ,

in `controller.java`

I guess this is the place that I should change the result stored place .

```
`public class Controller {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String crawlStorageFolder = "/data/crawl/root";
        int numberOfCrawlers = 7;

        CrawlConfig config = new CrawlConfig();
        config.setCrawlStorageFolder(crawlStorageFolder);`
```

First ,I don't know what is the file dictionary of `"/data/crawl/root"` .

Then I try to change to `"C:\Fraps\try"` .It creates a folder called frontier with some unknown file ,like je.lck, je.info.0...

In my understanding , `crawler4j` can work with finding external linkages and content parsing .

Do It mean many different `html` file that contain the web contents should be appeared in this  `crawlStorageFolder` ?

In other words , I can download the html files (text inside) through `crawler4j`? Or What should I download through `crawler4j` ?

Answer (score 2):

The `crawlStorageFolder` is a folder where intermediate crawl data is stored. It is **not** a folder to store any kind of parsed and downloaded HTML content.

Check [this](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j/blob/master/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/crawler/CrawlConfig.java) for a configuration description.

If you want to download and store the fetched data, you have to implement this behaviour in your custom crawler implementation, which should extend `WebCrawler`.

Check the example on [GitHub](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j).